# Partition Probability Proof

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I'm tasked with proving the following Lemma:

Let X be a set of $n^1$ < n elements, and B $\subset$ X, |B| = k. Suppose $P_1, P_2,...P_r$ are random partitions of X, where each $P_i$ partitions X into 2k equal sized sets $P_{i_1},...P_{i_k}$. There is a constant $c^1$ such that if r = $c^1$lgn, then with probability 1 - 1/$n^c$, for every x $\epsilon$ B there is some $P_{i_j}$ such that $P_{i_j} \cap $ B = {x}. I.e., some set in some partition contains x and no other members of B.

I think this lemma could be reduced into a balls and boxes probability problem. I'm not looking for an answer but rather any hints on how to approach a proof for this.